# PHP Script Unknown Error

Tags: php, if-statement, post, for-loop

I have a registration form that the user enters data in. Then after it is posted to the same page and checked for null fields, the variables are put in the `$_SESSION` array and the user is directed to another form to enter another set of data in a table. 
 After posting those variables, the variables from the previous page are extracted from `$_SESSION` and the new values are checked for null entries. After they are checked in a for loop, php script mysteriously stops (`die("<h1> GOT HERE! </h1>")` no longer appears on the screen) and the page keeps loading. After waiting for a while the page reloads itself. 
I've been using `die()` for a while now to find the error, but it just doesn't echo between the for-loop and the if statement, and there is no apparent reason why it shouldn't. Here have a look:

```
    <?php
     session_start();
    function sanitize($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    } 
    if($_SESSION["registering"] != 1){
    die("This page is to be used only when registering. <a href=\"tmcgb.com\">Go to home</a> page and select the seminar you want and click Register");
    }else if($_SESSION["registered"] == 1){
    die("You have already registered. Thank you. You can no longer access this page. To view your registration report, <a href=\"registration_report.php\"> click here. </a>");

    }else{

    $id = sanitize($_SESSION["id"]);
    $attendees = sanitize($_SESSION["attendees"]);
    $ref_code = sanitize($_SESSION["Ref_Code"]);
    $email = sanitize($_SESSION["email"]);
    $prefix = sanitize($_SESSION["prefix"]);
    $first_name = sanitize($_SESSION["first_name"]);
    $last_name = sanitize($_SESSION["last_name"]);
    $company = sanitize($_SESSION["company"]);
    $address1 = sanitize($_SESSION["address1"]);
    $address2 = sanitize($_SESSION["address2"]);
    $user_city = sanitize($_SESSION["city"]);
    $phone = sanitize($_SESSION["phone"]);
    $responsibility = sanitize($_SESSION["responsibility"]);
    $who_referred = sanitize($_SESSION["who-referred"]);
    $role = sanitize($_SESSION["role"]);

    $server = "MYREAL_DATABASE_SERVER";
    $username = "CORRECT_USERNAME";
    $password = "CORRECT_PASSWORD";
    $dbname = "DB_NAME";

    $conn = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $dbname);

    $query = "
        SELECT *
        FROM Seminar_Detail
        WHERE Detail_id = '". $id ."'
    ";

    $result = $conn->query($query);
    if($result->num_rows == 0 ){
      header("Location: ManagementSeminars.php");
    }

    $seminar = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $name = $seminar["Seminar_Name"];
    $city = $seminar["City"];
    $from = $seminar["From"];
    $to = $seminar["To"];
    $fee = '';

    $query = "SELECT Value FROM Fee WHERE Seminar_Name = '". $name ."' AND Currency = 'GBP'";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $fee = $row["Value"];
    }


    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
        $terminate = 0;
        for($i = 1; i < ($attendees + 1); $i++){
            if(isset($_POST["prefix-".$i]) && isset($_POST["first_name-".$i]) && isset($_POST["last_name-".$i]) && isset($_POST["position-".$i])){
                $terminate = 0;
            }else{
                $terminate = 1;
            }
        }
        die("<h1>".$terminate."</h1>");
            if($terminate != 1){
                $server = "SERVER";
                $username = "USERNAME";
                $password = "PASSWORD";
                $dbname = "DBNAME";

                $conn = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $dbname);
                $query = "
                INSERT INTO Registry (Seminar_Name, Number_Attendees, Email, Prefix, First_Name, Last_Name, Company, `Address 1`, `Address 2`, City, Phone, Responsibility, Role, Who_Referred, Ref_Code)
                VALUES ('". $name ."', '". $attendees ."', '".$email."', '".$prefix."', '".$first_name."', '".$last_name."', '".$company."', '".$address1."', '".$address2."', '".$user_city."', '".$phone."', '".$responsibility."', '".$role."', '".$who_referred."', '".$ref_code."')
                ";
                $conn->query($query);

                //ignore this part please
                /*$query = "SELECT Registry_ID FROM Registry WHERE Ref_Code = '". $_SESSION["Ref_Code"] ."'";
                $result = $conn->query($query);
                $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
                $registry_id = $row["Registry_ID"];
                $attendee_first_name = "";
                $attendee_last_name = "";
                $attendee_position = "";

                $stmt = $conn->prepare("
                INSERT INTO Attendee (First_Name, Last_Name, Position, Registry_ID)
                Values (?, ?, ?, ?)
                ");
                $stmt->bindParam("ssss", $attendee_first_name, $attendee_last_name, $attendee_position, $registry_id);
                for($i = 1; $i < $_SESSION["attendees"] + 1; $i++){
                    $attendee_first_name = sanitize($_POST["first_name-".$i]);
                    $attendee_last_name = sanitize($_POST["last_name-".$i]);
                    $attendee_position = sanitize($_POST["position-".$i]);
                    $stmt->execute();
                }*/
            }else{
                $errorMessage = "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable'>
                    <strong>Oops!</strong> You have not entered all values.
                </div>";
            }

    }
}
?>
```

I am positive that it is not a syntax error. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You're not error checking your queries.

Comment: why are you connecting more than once?

Comment: @JayBlanchard is correct. put some error reporting on your page so that you will get the real error.

Comment: would that normally cause the error, the script is not even reaching that part.

Comment: I also see two columns bearing reserved words of `From` and `To`, not always a good idea.

Comment: yes but you see, execution doesn't even reach that spot. See the die()? It doesn't even show. There doesn't seem to be a reason.

Comment: As for @anantkumarsingh, i did put error checking, and the only error to appear is a Notice: for an undefined index. but the code doesn't stop at that index so i'm assuming it isn't our fatal error.

Comment: *"I am positive that it is not a syntax error."* - As @JayBlanchard pointed out earlier, you're not checking for possible errors. Please don't assume success right away. Always test your code first using error checking. Use http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - If there are no errors, then something may be failing *silently*. Right Sam? ;-)

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Your `sanitize` function is USELESS to protect against this.

Comment: *It just may be Ralph.* Where do people get this stuff @Fred-ii-?

Comment: @MarcB They scrapped out the prepared statements method in thinking that'll work better, *ahem, right*. - *cough*.

Comment: i tried the query in phpmyadmin, and it ran, i also used `die()` at every line throughout the code, and it just doesn't echo after the for loop and before the if statement. I also had a syntax check over all of the code, and it returned no syntax errors. I will use the two links offered by @Fred-ii-. any more suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: *No idea Sam, no idea* - @JayBlanchard hey, where'd lunch go? Lordie, I'm famished. Anything left in that pick-ah-nick basket?

Comment: @MarcB What would be better?

Comment: *Oooo, I have to go fill 'er up Ralph. Getting a little famished myself.* It's too bad that part of the editing cannot be for 'handles' because some need to change theirs @Fred-ii-

Comment: @Brainiac someone's provided an answer for you below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be in this line

```
for($i = 1; i < ($attendees + 1); $i++){
```

You missed `$` sign in `i`. It should be:

```
for($i = 1; $i < ($attendees + 1); $i++){
```

---

Having used [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php), would have signaled an `undefined constant i` notice.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: ah, [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) would have signaled an `undefined constant i` notice, had they been using that in the first place ;-)

Comment: is there a reason why error reporting didn't show this? I had it set to E_ALL

Comment: @Brainiac you need to display them `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Yep this turned out to be it. Thanks a lot. It took way too much time. But i don't understand how the die() statement worked in the loop. I'm guessing the loop iterated indefinitely?

Comment: also @Fred-ii- thanks for the `ini_set` thing. I'm sure that i'll be using that a lot.

Comment: @Brainiac You're welcome. Glad to see it worked out, *cheers*